# Spring boot - Should i create my own DMS, or integrate with AWS S3

Tags: database, spring-boot, amazon-s3

i am implementing a system where i need to store too many documents. I want to ask you if should i use my own database, or it is better to integrate with aws s3?

If i integrate with aws s3, can someone explain how to put and get data in chunks?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried integrating already? any errors or steps where things went wrong?

Comment: I have intregrated already, but now i trying to implement functionality to get data in chunks

Comment: ah, i see. mostly, here on stack, we help you with specific, narrowed down situations, usually code related. your question came up on this queue which asked me to comment and help out. but, there is nothing stopping you from waiting to see if someone can post a answer.